# How to get all objects using RubyZoho API

Tags: ruby, rspec, zoho

RubyZoho::Crm::Account.all returns 202 accounts while there are more accounts.
The same RubyZoho::Crm::Contact.all & RubyZoho::Crm::Products.all.

what can i to do to receive all objects?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some research I did, the restriction of 200 entries is setted in Zoho Api.
The way i have found to get all records using RubyZoho:

```
def get_zoho_objects module_name
   objects = []
   first_index = 1
   block_size = 200
   to_index = block_size
   loop do
      puts "from index: #{first_index} to index: #{to_index}"
      return_objects = RubyZoho.configuration.api.some(module_name, first_index, to_index)
      break if return_objects == nil
      objects += return_objects
      first_index = to_index + 1
      to_index += block_size
   end
   objects
end
```

usage:

```
all_accounts = get_zoho_objects "Accounts"
```